# How to tag a changeset or a changelog file with a tag - webdevops/liquibase

Tags: postgresql, liquibase, liquibase-sql

I need to tag a changeset for rollback.

**Tried this**

**Way 1**

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/liquibase/ -e "LIQUIBASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://host/dbname" -e "LIQUIBASE_USERNAME=username" -e "LIQUIBASE_PASSWORD=pass" webdevops/liquibase:postgres tag -Dliquibase.tag='version0.1'
```

or

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/liquibase/ -e "LIQUIBASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://host/dbname" -e "LIQUIBASE_USERNAME=username" -e "LIQUIBASE_PASSWORD=pass" webdevops/liquibase:postgres tag 'version0.1'
```

on running this i get

> /entrypoint: line 172: exec: tag: not found

**Way 2**

```
<changeSet  id="3"  author="nvoxland">
        <tagDatabase  tag="version_1.3"/>    
            <addLookupTable  
                existingTableName="person"  existingColumnName="state"  
                newTableName="state"  newColumnName="id"  newColumnDataType="char(2)"/>  
    </changeSet>
```

Or

```
    <changeSet  id="3"  author="nvoxland">
        <tagDatabase  tag="version_1.3"/>    
        <addLookupTable  
            existingTableName="person"  existingColumnName="state"  
            newTableName="state"  newColumnName="id"  newColumnDataType="char(2)"/>  
    </changeSet>
```

Error

> Invalid content was found starting with element 'addLookupTable'.

How do i tag and rollback?

Answer (score 0):

Can you separate out the tagDatabase as it's own changeset?
Something like

```
    <changeSet  id="3"  author="mo">
        <tagDatabase  tag="version_1.3"/>
    </changeSet>
```

Comment: I had tried that. But it just tagged the changeset this tagDatabase is in. Rest all changesets above or below than that didn't got that tag

Comment: The tag will put a marker in the changelog table.  If you want to do something for each changeset, you could add a label, label="version_1.3" to each and every changeset with regards to version 1.3

<changeSet id="3 author="mo" label="version_1.3">
The tag marker will allow you to rollback to that point.
The labels are just informational markers for you to know what is a part of version 1.3.